# Format output of var_export evaluate text variable if it corresponds to a type

Tags: php, variables, formatting

the output is show in protectec document i can copy it, but the script is ported to a sandbox: 
https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/biCw

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/biC6 `//with Object Class`

i have merge a couple of script that find in internet.
and get this two function:

this to get Type of Variable passed but not working correctly

```
private function GetType($var) {
    if (is_array($var)) {
        return "array";
    }

    if (is_bool($var)) {
        return "boolean";
    }

    if (is_float($var)) {
        return "float";
    }

    if (is_int($var)) {
        return "integer";
    }

    if (is_null($var)) {
        return "NULL";
    }

    if (is_numeric($var)) {
        return "numeric";
    }

    if (is_object($var)) {
        return "object";
    }

    if (is_resource($var)) {
        return "resource";
    }

    if (is_string($var)) {
        return "string";
    }

    return "unknown";
}
```

this Function to Parse and Formated `var_export` output text:

```
private function VarExportFormat($Var) {
    $textvar    = '';
    $textvar    = var_export($Var, true);
    $textvar    = preg_replace("/^([ ]*)(.*)/m", '$1$1$2', $textvar);
    $textvarArr = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $textvar);
    foreach ($textvarArr as $key => $value) {
        preg_match('~=>\\s(.*?),~', $value, $newvalue);
        if (!empty($newvalue)) {
            $newvalue[1] = str_replace("'", "", $newvalue[1]);
            $typeval=$this->GetType($newvalue[1]);
            $value = str_replace("=> ", "=> ".$typeval.'('.strlen($newvalue[1]).') ', $value);
            $textvarArr[$key]=$value;
        }
    }
    $textvarArr = preg_replace(["/\s*array\s\($/", "/\)(,)?$/", "/\s=>\s$/"], [NULL, ']$1', ' => array ['], $textvarArr);
    $textvar    = join(PHP_EOL, array_filter(["array ["] + $textvarArr));
    if (substr($textvar, -1) == '[') {
        echo var_dump($textvar);
        $textvar = str_replace("[", "[]", $textvar);
    }
    $textvar = highlight_string("<?php \n#output of Variable:\n" . $textvar . ";\n?>", true);
    return $textvar;
}
```

and get and ouput like this, with type of array:

First View Aftr Edit the script

```
<?php
#output de la Variable Solicitada:
array [
    'SIS' => array [
        'ABS' => array [
            'DATA' => array [
            ],
            'LIST' => array [
            ],
        ],
        'HTTPR' => array [
            'HTTPST' => true,
            'HTTPM' => 'POST',
            'PROTOCOL' => 'HTTP',
            'CHECK' => false,
            'JSON' => array [
                'CHECK' => 'MIX',
            ],
        ],
```

current ouput with all edit:

```
<?php
#output of Variable:
array [
    'SIS' => array [
        'ABS' => array [
            'DATA' => array [
            ],
            'LIST' => array [
            ],
        ],
        'HTTPR' => array [
            'HTTPST' => string(4) true,
            'HTTPM' => string(4) 'POST',
            'PROTOCOL' => string(4) 'HTTP',
            'CHECK' => string(5) false,
            'JSON' => array [
                'CHECK' => string(3) 'MIX',
            ],
        ],
        'ERROR' => array [
            'TYPE' => string(4) NULL,
        ],
        'MAIL' => array [
            'TRACK' => array [
                'SMG' => string(4) NULL,
            ],
        ],
        'IDFORM' => string(10) 'f-sis-0320',
        'PROCESS' => string(6) 'p-test',
        'EXECTIMEUSAGE' => array [
            'STANDBY' => numeric(18) -1570214309.358045,
        ],
        'MEMORYUSAGE' => array [
            'STANDBY' => numeric(4) '1.63',
            'STANDBYTXT' => string(7) '1.63 Mb',
        ],
```

**How can I get the types of the existing types in the string and place it in the output as it comes out.
it is for development purpose.**

**True is evaluated as String and Float as numeric.**

Comment: Please do not post any images with code in them. This is a programming site, where code should be posted as text. Thanks!

Comment: @Levon images is and PDF output to report to development parse Data,  How do you think I'm going to upload it? I don't have the source data and it's dynamic... have you read the post at least ???

Comment: @Levon the output is show in protectec document i can copy itbut the script is ported to a sandbox: https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/biCw

Answer (score 0):

i have solve this problem:

```
<?php
#Variable:

$Test                            = [];
$Test['Check1']                  = null;
$Test['Check2']                  = [];
$Test['Check2']['int']           = 20;
$Test['Check2']['float']         = 20.35;
$Test['Check2']['string']        = 'Hello World';
$Test['Check2']['bolean']        = true;
$Test['Check2']['array']         = [];
$Test['Check2']['array']['data'] = 'Array Text';
class Example {
    function foo_function() {
        return "Hello World! Object";
    }
}
$var_object                         = new Example;
$Test['Check2']['array']['object']  = $var_object;
$Test['Check2']['array']['object2'] = $var_object->foo_function();

#Script Type:
function myGetType($var) {
    if (is_array($var)) {
        return "array";
    }

    if (in_array($var, array("true", "false"), true)) {
        return "boolean";
    }

    if ((int) $var == $var && is_numeric($var)) {
        return "integer" . '(' . strlen($var) . ')';
    }

    if ((float) $var == $var && is_numeric($var)) {
        return "float" . '(' . strlen($var) . ')';
    }

    if (is_null($var)) {
        return "NULL";
    }

    if (is_object($var)) {
        return "object";
    }

    if (is_resource($var)) {
        return "resource";
    }

    if (is_string($var)) {
        return "string" . '(' . strlen($var) . ')';
    }

    return "unknown";
}

#Script Analisis:
function VarExportFormat($Var) {
    $textvar    = '';
    $textvar    = var_export($Var, true);
    $textvar    = preg_replace("/^([ ]*)(.*)/m", '$1$1$2', $textvar);
    $textvarArr = preg_split("/\r\n|\n|\r/", $textvar);
    # Analisis del tipo.
    foreach ($textvarArr as $key => $value) {
        preg_match('~=>\\s(.*?),~', $value, $newvalue);
        if (!empty($newvalue)) {
            $newvalue[1]      = str_replace("'", "", $newvalue[1]);
            $typeval          = myGetType($newvalue[1]);
            $value            = str_replace("=> ", "=> " . $typeval . ' ', $value);
            $textvarArr[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    $textvarArr = preg_replace(["/\s*array\s\($/", "/\)(,)?$/", "/\s=>\s$/"], [NULL, ']$1', ' => array ['], $textvarArr);
    $textvar    = join(PHP_EOL, array_filter(["array ["] + $textvarArr));
    if (substr($textvar, -1) == '[') {
        $textvar = str_replace("[", "[]", $textvar);
    }
    $textvar = highlight_string("<?php \n#output of Variable:\n" . $textvar . ";\n?>", true);
    return $textvar;
}

echo VarExportFormat($Test);
```

Link to testing sandbox:

https://wtools.io/php-sandbox/biDk

if detect anhy issues plz leave a comment.